# Contenteditable update PHP, SQL, AJAX - in network it's showing success?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having problems updating changed text to SQL, via PHP and Ajax.

I am not sure which one is not correct, is it the data which is sent through Ajax, or a problem with the PHP file?

This is my HTML file

```
<tr>
<td class="editingTab" contenteditable='true' class="texting">{{user.id}}</td>
<td contenteditable='true' >{{user.first_name}}</td>
<td contenteditable='true' >{{user.last_name}}</td>
<td contenteditable='true' >{{user.email}}</td></tr>
```

This is JS file

```
$(document).on('blur','table td',function(){

   var name = $(this).text();

   var last = $(this).text();   

   var email = $(this).text();


    var getId = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
         $.post('update.php',{name:name, last:last, email:email, id:getId}, function(data){

           if(!data) {
     alert("Failed");
    }   
    else {console.log(data);
    }
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

And here is the PHP file

```
 <?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','nemkeang','nemkic23','users');

    $id = $POST_['getId'];
    $name =$_POST['name'];
    $last =$_POST['last'];
    $email =$_POST['email'];

    $sql = "UPDATE user 
    SET first_name = '".$name."', 
        last_name = '".$last."', 
       email = '".$email."' 
    WHERE id = '".$id."'";

    if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    echo  "success: ".$name." ";

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is at getting id so update operation is going to failed.try this...

The `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.So use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

```
<?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','nemkeang','nemkic23','users');

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']);  //
    $name =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['name']);
    $last =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['last']);
    $email =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);

    $sql = "UPDATE user 
    SET first_name = '$name', 
        last_name = '$last', 
       email = '$email' 
    WHERE id = '$id';

    if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    echo  "success: ".$name." ";

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```